# Get Angular directive name from TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

I implemented next AngularJS directive:

```
export module Directives {

    export class PasswordsMatch implements ng.IDirective {

        public static Factory(name: string) : ng.IDirectiveFactory {
            return () => new PasswordsMatch();
        }

        require = 'ngModel';            
        link = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: Attributes): void => {
            // how to get directive name here?
        };
    }
}
```

which is registered in another script file as:

```
class Application {
    private app: ng.IModule;

    constructor() {     

        // Controllers

        // Directives           
        this.app.directive('ngPasswordsMatch', Directives.PasswordsMatch.Factory());
    }        
}
```

Is it possible to get directive name inside link function without passing directive name to Factory function (I don't want to duplicate directive name)?

Answer (score 0):

You could have directive name outside in variable, so that it can be accessible anywhere inside.

```
let directiveName = 'ngPasswordsMatch'; //declared directive name as string
export module Directives {

  export class PasswordsMatch implements ng.IDirective {

    public static Factory(name: string): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
      return () => new PasswordsMatch();
    }

    require: 'ngModel';
    link = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: Attributes): void => {
      console.log(directiveName); //directive name accessible here
    };
  }
}

this.app.directive(directiveName, Directives.PasswordsMatch.Factory());
```

By having which you could say variable `directiveName` to get directive name.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I could. But in this case I get sort of shared/global variable which I would like to avoid. I will clarify my question. Nevertheless, thanks for the reply!